# Embed one processes JFrame into another processes JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 related processes, and our designer wants the second processes window embedded in our main window.

The windows are JDialogs but could easily be refactored to another form to make this work, what I don't know is if this can be done or not.  I need a window inside one processes window to be controlled by another process.

Can this be done in Java?

Thanx

Bodger

Comment: Is it possible to convert the other process to a thread so they can share references to the GUI

Comment: I built them as separate programs with different java namespaces, its a "plugin" framework for lack of a better word.  The main program and the "plugin" communicate over a socket, but they display separate windows.  I can look into that but was hoping to keep the programs separate.

Comment: I am going to discuss with my colleagues the thread re-architecture and see if it will fly.  I will get back later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to be careful what is happening on the event dispatching thread.

Comment: But more importantly how can I get the seperate processes window inside another window?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your question.  What do you mean by process?   Secondly if that was important why did you say it can easily be done?

Comment: >You need to be more specific about your question. What do you mean by process? Secondly if that was important why did you say it can easily be done?<  Different processes mean they are separate java programs with a common jar file.  I start them in different jvms from the commandline it would be like java -jar my.jar MainClass1 and java -jar my.jar MainClass2.   What would be easy is to convert the main screen from a JDialog to a JPane or JWindow as necessary.  The JDialog is used to display it in it's own independant window.